# C# Button Click with additional Parameter

Tags: c#, button, click

I want to execute something with a button click. But for that I need an additional parameter "string[] args".

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string[] args)
```

If I use this parameter, I get an error because I have to specify it somehow in the EventHandler which I do not know how to do?

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Could someone explain to me how I would have to proceed here?

Comment: Why do you need the string[] args? The button event handler can't send anything for that parameter.

Comment: Its a custom one I need for the code below.

Comment: (sender, EventArgs) => { buttonNext_Click(sender, EventArgs, item.NextTabIndex); }; I used that for now. It also works

Comment: I would be a bit careful using lambdas as event handlers. One problem is that it is quite difficult to unregister them. In some cases that does not matter, but you need to know when it does to write correct code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this code in form.designer.cs

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
  string[] args = new string[] { "param1", "param2" };
  MyButton myButton = new MyButton(args);
  this.SuspendLayout();
  // 
  //myButton
  // 
  myButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230, 121);
  myButton.Name = "myButton";
  myButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(175, 31);
  myButton.TabIndex = 0;
  myButton.Text = "Test Click";
  myButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  myButton.ButtonClick += MyButton_ButtonClick;


  // 
  // Form1
  // 
  this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
  this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
  this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
  this.Controls.Add(myButton);
  this.Name = "Form1";
  this.Text = "Form1";
  this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
private void MyButton_ButtonClick(object Sender, System.EventArgs e, string[] args)
{
   //do works.......
   MyButton btn = Sender as MyButton;
   MessageBox.Show(args[0] + " -- " + args[1] + " -- " + btn.Name);       
}
```

and add this class

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
   public event ClickEventHandler ButtonClick;
   public delegate void ClickEventHandler(object Sender, EventArgs e, string[] args);
   private string[] _args;
   public MyButton(string[] args)
   {
      _args = args;
   } 

   protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
   {
      if (ButtonClick != null)
      {
          ButtonClick(this, e, _args);
      }
   }
}
```

This code works perfectly.